# Iptable rule to ssh over the internet

Tags: ssh, security, iptables, firewall

I've a server `abc.example.com` and a remote desktop `zzz.example.com`. I'm using SSH over a custom port, say, 6789. Whenever my firewall is off, I'm able to connect to the server successfully. But, as soon as I start my firewall, in vain.

Moreover, I want to allow ssh session only between `abc.example.com` and `zzz.example.com`, for security reasons.

This is the rule that I have added to my iptables on the server,

```
iptables -A INPUT -s zzz.example.com -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -p tcp --dport 6789 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: When you append that to the bottom of your rule set, is it below any `reject` rule that is being matched before your new rule matches?

Comment: no, in fact I do not have any `reject` rule in the iptables. Moreover, it works without `-s` parameter. But, that would make the system vulnerable as it would allow anyone to connect.

Comment: Is the remote desktop machine behind a firewall with respect to the server?

Comment: yes, I'm using iptables as firewall.

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing a rule to enable traffic from `ESTABLISHED` connections, then you will need a rule allowing traffic from your host to the remote system. It is common to have a first rule like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Then you can enable your access with a rule like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s zzz.example.com -p tcp --dport 6789 -j ACCEPT
```

Alternatively you can use a firewall builder like `shorewall` and enable `port knocking` to open the port for a few seconds when needed.

If your ssh daemon supports `tcp_wrapers`, then you can limit access with the `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` files.   Even if you have fixed the firewall, you may want to look at using this capability to notify you when remote connections are made.  The following rules blocks a number of country domains, and send an email on every succ

```
sshd :          ALL \
            EXCEPT .ar .au .br .by .cl .co .cz .do .eg .gt \
                .id .il .in .jp .ma .mx .nl .pe .pk .pl .pt \
                .ro .rs .ru .sa .sg .tr .tw .ua .vn .za \
                .ae .at .bg .gh .hr .hu .ke .kz .lt .md \
                .my .no .sk .uy .ve : \
            spawn (/bin/echo "SSH connection to %N from %n[%a] allowed" | \
                /usr/bin/mailx -s "SSH Allowed" you@example.com)
```

EDIT: Using domain names in rules is not a good idea:

- DNS lookups may not be available when the rules are loaded.  (This is when the name gets converted to an IP address.)
- Clients without static IP addresses may get new addresses, which are not available due DNS caching.  Old IP addresses may be left with access, while the new address doesn't have access.  Static IP addresses with local host entries work reasonably reliably.

If you have a dynamic address either secure access from a relatively large IP address range, or use port knocking.  You can use `fail2ban` or a similar program to lock out addresses which are probing your ssh service.  `tcpwrappers` can be used as above to put restrictions on which addresses can connect, and add additional logging.   If you don't connect often, you may want to log successful as well as unsuccessful attempts.

Comment: BillThor, firstly I apologize for late reply. Now, I've tried what you said, but it didn't work. However, when I write the latter rule, it shows me something like this in the iptables, `115-111-201-123.static.zzzbroadband.yy.57150`. Then I checked the tcpdump on the port. I found it to be communicating from a different address. I did a traceroute from server to desktop and vice versa. Found out that I need to add one more rule `116-111-254-123.static.zzzbroadband.yy`. It worked. Is it because I'm using a dns service instead of static ip?

Comment: Either your dyndns entry is incorrect, or your IP address changed after the rule was loaded.  If you have a host entry, it may override the DNS entry.  The DNS lookup will be done once when you start your rules (and will fail if DNS is not reachable).  Consider using port knocking, or reloading the rule when the IP address changes (whenever your dyndns update needs to run.  DNS caching may cause the old IP address to be used.